# Can't upgrade Windows 7 to Windows 8 - registry error

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-upgrade

I am upgrading my Windows 7 setup (dual partition, one hdd), and I got this

> Windows could not update registry data, cancelling install

And the setup is aborted, leaving an undeletable $UPGRADE.~OS and a windows.bt folder

What can be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried running a registry cleaning utility like cccleaner?

Comment: Run a chkdsk /r on the hard drive.

Comment: I did mydefrag, scandisk, ccleaner and the full surface scan utility from western digital

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sometimes the result of 3 things:

1. Windows rot (often updates will screw things up)
2. Registry cleaners
3. Bugs with MS software (You may have found a bug with the Windows 8 installer)

I would strongly advise you to do a clean install.

Comment: I opted to wipe the drive and do a clean install

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever messed with any registry key permissions? I recommend you back up your personal data, use the Upgrade Assistant to create USB/DVD (ISO) media, then boot from that and clean install Windows 8.